# How to highlight text permanently in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I know I can use `*bold*, /italic/, _underlined_, =verbatim= and ~code~, and, if you must, ‘+strike-through+’` to do some `markup` to text according to [org-mode documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html#Emphasis-and-monospace), but they are not enough for me(`bold` is not obvious when viewing the org file), I know I can customize `org-emphasis-alist`, but the documentation doesn't tell much. What I want is to highlight the text selected like `enriched-mode` like the image in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016713/1528712).

[image]

But `enriched-mode` will save the file as `text/enriched` format, and I have to use `enriched-mode` not `org-mode` itself.

So, how can I re-define or define a new markup(maybe customize `org-emphasis-alist`) to highlight text like `enriched-mode`, so

1. the highlight is permanent in this file(I can see the highlight in Emacs)
2. at the same time it can be exported into pdf or html file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can change what face is used to display bold (or any other) markup by adding a new entry to `org-emphasis-alist`.  For example, to make `*bold*` display in red, use

```
(add-to-list 'org-emphasis-alist
             '("*" (:foreground "red")
               ))
```

You will have to restart org-mode (with `org-mode-restart`) for this to take effect.

Trying to add new markup characters like this doesn't seem to work, it only changes how the existing markup is displayed in Emacs.

This doesn't affect exports at all.  `*bold*` still exports to whatever bold means in that format (e.g. `<b>bold</b>` in html or `\textbf{bold}` in Latex).

Comment: I use "(setq org-emphasis-alist (append org-emphasis-alist '(("`" bold))))" to create a new markup, but it doesn't work, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @CodyChan The first problem is with the `append`, which puts the new element at the end, but we need it at the beginning so it gets found first.  Just swap the arguments.  The second problem is that it appears to be impossible to add new markup, according to the `org-mode` [mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-02/msg00405.html).

Comment: How to make this change specific to the current file?

Comment: @Supernormal with hook.